# Is there a Java array/list which is statically typed AND variable length

Tags: java, arrays, list

This would be very handy as typecasting gets boring fast.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use generics (java 5), you can avoid all casting with

```
 List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
 myList.add(" a test");
 String temp = myList.get(0);
```

Unless I am missing something in your question that should cover both needs.

Comment: Thanks - I'm Flash guy learning Java and neither NetBeans nor google were giving me any help with that one!

Comment: Behind the scenes it still does it the old way by casting the objects b/c generics are only visible at compile time not at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand, what's so hard about:

```
List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
```

I guess you could define a class:

```
public class FooList extends ArrayList<Foo> {
    ...
}
```

if you want to avoid the angle brackets...

Comment: Extending a concrete class like ArrayList is serious ick. I would prefer to implement List, and forward all operations to an ArrayList that's contained as a member of FooList. Or, you can extend AbstractList.

Comment: Yeah, it isn't nice, for a simple structure like ArrayList with only one class generic, if can be handy when you get something complex like a Graph data structure with Nodes and Edges, all typed with each other! Yes, wrapping it would be nicer, but that's a nitpick against the question.

Answer (score 1):

If by "variable length" you mean that the size will change over time, then you probably want a LinkedList rather than an ArrayList:

```
print("List<Foo> fooList = new LinkedList<Foo>();");
```

That way you get better performance when adding a bunch of elements.